# Temporary Views and Auto Broadcast Join Error

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a query (given below) and when I run it sometimes Spark throws this error -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcasts via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 5m 56s
```

We extract the data from the source and apply several transformation logic at various steps in temporary views.

A simplified version of the query that I execute is -

```
create temporary view my_date AS
select max(max_eff_dt) as eff_dt
from (
      select max(eff_dt) as max_eff_dt from tableA
      union
      select max(eff_dt) as max_eff_dt from tableB
      union
      select max(eff_dt) as max_eff_dt from tableC
      );

create temporary view AS
select a.x, b.x, c.y, dt.eff_dt
from tableA a
inner join tableB  b
on a.x = b.x
inner join tableC c
on b.y = c.y
cross join my_date dt
where a.join_dt < dt.eff_dt
and   b.join_dt < dt.eff_dt
and   c.join_dt < dt.eff_dt;
```

However, the Spark does not throw this error always but only at certain times.

Can anyone please help me understand the reason of this error and alleviate the same. Although, `set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1` takes care of the error, I want to understand the reason for this error and how to modify my code to avoid this in the future.
Additionally, it will be great if someone can point me to any online resources about performance tuning of Spark-SQL queries.

Please let me know if additional information is required regarding the error.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Spark was broadcasting data for some of your joins and did not manage to broadcast the data within 300s. This 300s threshold is a default value for an internal configuration setting which you can change as follows:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", n)
```

where `n` is time in seconds. Increasing this threshold is one way how to avoid this error. Also depending on the size of your cluster it might help to tweak the value of `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` configuration. By setting value -1, you will totally disable broadcasting. The default value of this setting is `10MB`, so you may also check what value is set in your environment (by calling `spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")` ) and adjust the value. When Spark estimates that the size of the data is bigger than this threshold, then Spark will not broadcast and will choose different algorithm, mostly SortMergeJoin (assuming you did not use broadcast hint in your query). If you use broadcast hint in the query, then Spark will try to broadcast no matter what the estimated size is and it may fail if the data size is too large (either because of OOM error or because the error you are getting with the timeout).